# Validate and Process an uploaded Excel File - WebJob Vs Service Fabric MicroService

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-service-fabric

I have a user case where the user uploads an excel file through an **ASP.NET MVC 5 website or a Windows Store App**. The file contains an *e-Commerce products list*. This file needs to be validated first for the right format, data accuracy etc... After the validation is done, the date needs to be read and send a message like **AddProducts** which generates an event for all the products to be added. This app uses **AR+E**, so has to log all the events in **Azure Table Storage**. The non-functional requirement is that there may be thousands of people who will upload files from the web or the store app to their online store. The requests need to be processed one by one and if the processing is successful, the user will be notified immediately via *SignalR*.

Looked at few options like **Azure Worker roles**, **WebJobs** etc... The WebJob may be a fit but it's tie to the web role making to think of Service Fabric micro service. This service/job has to scale based on the requests that come from the ASP.NET MVC5 site as well as from the Windows Store application. When WebJob is being used, it can scale based on the website role it has attached to in my understanding.

Can I use the **Service Fabric Service** to achieve all of these from a single service end point (1) a REST end point with a POST action like */product-file/uploaded* (2) another end point like */product-file/checkstatus/myExcelFileName* (3) check the uploaded requests from **Azure Storage Queue** every 30 seconds and initiate the validation and processing of the file (4) validate and process the file? As you may notice, this service should have REST end points, access to a queue, a background job runner that utilizes CPU and IO operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can model this any number of ways with Service Fabric. If you're used to stateless workers with externalized state stores (Azure Queue, Table Storage, etc) you can certainly do that and scale by adding more instances like you would with worker roles. Service Fabric let's you write *stateless services* which are just general-purpose services that can host HTTP endpoints, run processing jobs, or whatever workload you have. That's fairly straight-forward if you don't want to think about the problem any differently, except that services aren't defined by VM roles so you can put a large number of services on a small number of VMs if you want.

Service Fabric also has *stateful services* where you actually have your state - queues and tables - co-located with your code inside the service (we make it highly-available and persistent for you). In which case, you can eliminate external state store dependencies. In this case, you scale differently too: instead of increasing the number of stateless workers, you *partition* the stateful services and spread the partitions across multiple machines to increase capacity. The difference with this approach is that your state stores scale with you so they don't become bottlenecks and single points of failure. You also have the benefit of local reads and transactional operations between queues and data stores, something you can't get otherwise.

Here's a look at how this model differs from a traditional 3-tier system: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-scenarios/

And of course you can set up HTTP endpoints with Web API as your ingress point for users, so they communicate with your service using the same POST actions you're used to.

Hope that helps.